# What is the difference between TD learning and TD search?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I tried reading https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/ICAPS/ICAPS13/paper/view/6037/6227 but it's incomprehensible without any examples or algorithms written.

1. What are main differences between the two?
2. When do the updates of estimated value function occur?
3. How are the actions chosen during training and how in test time?
4. Branching ?
5. Online vs offline?
6. On policy vs off policy?